# fatal error: functional: No such file or directory #include <functional>

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

I installed the Arduino IDE and decided to create a project. Installed all libraries. But I do not understand why such an error. Help I want to connect ESP8266 to Arduino Uno. I need the arduino to send data over Wi-Fi to ThingSpeak
In file included from C:\Users\Misha\Documents\Arduino\TestSketch\TestSketch.ino:4:0:
c:\Users\Misha\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClient.h:24:10: fatal error: memory: No such file or directory
#include 
^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

exit status 1

Compilation error: exit status 1
There were attempts to reinstall, but in vain.

Comment: If you have UNO + wifi module, it might be a wrong library (AVR compiler doesn't have anything from STL so no functional and so)

Comment: that library shouldn't be in Documents\Arduino\libraries. it is bundled with the esp8266 Arduino platform and only works there.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by wanting to call the libraries for ESP when it was necessary to refer to the module directly. And that call is possible only for the ESP board